# 2005 C200 Kompressor steering lock

Tags: engine, starting, mercedes-benz, steering-lock

My 2005 C200 Kompressor's steering wheel is locked and I can't turn the key; the remote opens the doors but the dashboard lights switch off in about five seconds. The battery's voltage is 12.22 now but 12.84 is indicated on the battery itself: can this be the problem? The fuel tank was run empty earlier in the day so my son threw petrol directly in the tank, drove home, and later we encountered the steering wheel lock problem.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Have you parked with the steering wheel at an angle and some pressure on the wheels? Sometimes, one has to push with force on the steering wheel to release the side forces in order to unlock the steering wheel.